# make drop-down appear when checkbox is selected

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, checkbox, seam

I am making a Java/HTML program using Seam. I am trying to get an `<h:selectOneMenu>` to show up when a `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` is checked. I got it to do it by using "onclick="form.submit()" in the checkbox and putting the drop-down in an `<s:div rendered>`, but whenever the page reloads, the variable that is being used by the dropdown is reset to the top  choice. I'm pretty sure it is because of the `<s:div>`. Does anyone know how I can make it keep the correct choice in the drop-down? Thank you.

Here is the code for the checkbox and the drop-down:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" value="#{printLabel.code}" label="barcode" onclick="changeDropdowns()"/>
<br />
<s:div rendered="#{printLabel.code}">
    <h:outputLabel id="locationLabel" value="&#160;&#160;&#160;Location"/>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="locationDrop" value="#{printLabel.codeLoc}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{printLabel.getBarcodeTypes()}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu> 
</s:div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want todo it with ajax you can do it like this:
might be some other event then onclick

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" value="#{printLabel.code}" label="barcode" >
        <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="parentdiv" />

</<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<br />
<s:div id="parentdiv">
<s:div rendered="#{printLabel.code}">
    <h:outputLabel id="locationLabel" value="&#160;&#160;&#160;Location"/>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="locationDrop" value="#{printLabel.codeLoc}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{printLabel.getBarcodeTypes()}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu> 
</s:div>
</s:div>
```

add tag libary

```
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
```

Comment: I've never used ajax before. when i use <a4j:support> it says its an unknown tag. do i need to download a library or anything

Comment: nah you need to add gthe tag libary among the others at top of page edited my post about it, it is a part of richfaces

Comment: ya i figured that out right after i posted my comment lol. But it is still doing the same thing

Comment: What scope do you haev on your printLabel ? You need to have Page or higher if you want to save the value after the page is reloaded.

Comment: In my printLabel bean i have @Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)

Comment: I changed the ScopeType to PAGE and it works now. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: No problem, conversation could be used but then you need to create it to a long running conversation and that is a bit more hassle if you don't need it as a long running.